# How to check if an e-mail address already exists in a file database?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have an Array List which has elements that are objects of a class with the following fields: `ID, name, surname, email, password, subject and literature` (I am trying to create an application which saves the student's accounts for school).

The `literature` field itself is an Array List with a max of 3 elements. Now I am checking if a String input is an existing email address and I want to access the Array List's email field, but I can't figure out how. Can you help me?

Comment: Select e-mail from Table where e-mail like 'a@b.com'

Comment: What's a file database? Your own plain file or some library?

Comment: You have to iterate over the list and get the email field from each object using its accessor method, then compare it with your e-mail. If you want to be more efficient, you should create a hash map instead. And why do you use the word "database"?

Comment: @OP: When you said '*an existing email address*', how should one understand it? Is it stored somewhere other than your *runtime* `ArrayList` object? If yes, post those details.

Comment: I have stored all the information about every student's account into a file, that's why I call it a file database (even though I know the name may not feel right). I used object serialization to access this file and, the moment I want to check the email (or password) I copy all the information in the file into the array list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to iterate your array list and compare each email to the given email.
Look at this example:
This is the user object declaration

```
import java.util.List;
// This is the user object
public class User {

    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String subject;
    public List<String> literature;

    public User(String id, String name, String surname, String email, String password,
            String subject, List<String> literature) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.literature = literature;
    }
}
```

And this is where we fill the users and check if the email is contained in the users ArrayList

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class main {

    private static List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creates the users
        User user1 = new User("1", "John", "Addams", "john@mail.com", "j123", "Math", new ArrayList<String>());
        User user2 = new User("2", "Mary", "Stall", "mary@mail.com", "m123", "Math", new ArrayList<String>());
        User user3 = new User("3", "Kurt", "Metten", "kurt@mail.com", "k123", "Math", new ArrayList<String>());

        // Adds the users to the array
        users.add(user1);
        users.add(user2);
        users.add(user3);

        System.out.println(isExistingEmail("john@mail.com")); // True
        System.out.println(isExistingEmail("some mail@mail.com")); // False
    }

    private static boolean isExistingEmail(String email) {
        // Iterates all the users
        for (User user: users) {
            // Checks if the user email is equal to the email parameter
            if (user.email.equals(email)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```